# how to change numpy version with miniforge

Tags: python, macos, numpy, pip, virtualenv

I have installed miniforge on my mac , in that using a 'local env' on jupyter notebook. I can't change the numpy version (need to downgrade to 1.19.5) on this kernel, have tried:
(1)pip install numpy==1.19.5 &
(2)conda install -c conda-forge numpy=1.19.5.

numpy version seems to be changing easily on conda-ipython3 kernel, but my project is running on 'local env'

very new to all this, still learning. Please help

Answer (score 0):

first make sure that your local environment is activated by running: `.../{your venv folder path}/Scripts/activate`. Because if you install numpy on the wrong virtual environment then it won't work.
Then uninstall numpy by running `pip uninstall numpy`. Then install the numpy version you want.

Comment: thanks for your help. I tried your method and made sure my local env is active in local terminal, re-installed numpy but its still showing the earlier version. Any advice on what else I should be checking to ensure I get the version I want in local env. Thanks

Comment: you can specify the version like this: ```pip install numpy==1.2.3```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to ensure you have desired `numpy` version:

1. Activate your local environment
2. Uninstall any previously installed `numpy` version by using:

```
pip uninstall numpy
```

3. Install the desired `numpy` version:

```
pip install numpy=1.19.5
```

4. Check the installed version of `numpy`:

```
pip freeze
```

If you want to export the package list use:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```